# Which technologies/commodities were available during the 30s in the USA?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu, historical-settings, trail-of-cthulhu

I'm going to GM Trail of Cthulhu and would like to know if there is any site that aggregates this kind of information. I've already found this site http://www.paper-dragon.com/1939/; any other suggestions?

Comment: You will probably have to be more specific. "Technologies" is such a wide term. Cars? Radios? Packaged foods? What exactly are you aiming for?

Comment: See [Are Campaign Research Questions On Topic](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/570/are-campaign-research-questions-on-topic) for the community's consensus on this kind of question. Short form: allowed. Now, "too broad" may be a fair criticism however.

Comment: Hi TheLinuxLich, and welcome to the site. As noted by Mxyzplk, your question is on-topic but is currently too broad; it's difficult to tell exactly what you're looking for, or judge the quality of one suggested site over another. Please see our [faq].

Comment: Some suggestions to narrow it down: You already have a site listed, in what way does that not solve your problem? Alternatively, what problem are you trying to solve with this list of sites? Having that bit of context may help us zero in on what you're looking for.

Comment: As another way to help narrow your focus, take a look at the first scenario or two that you wish to run and think about what assumptions, machines, and products might reasonably be brought forward during play. Make notes of these things and give them a level of importance. For example, how important is the invention of collared shirts compared to the availability of telephones? Focus initially on things which by themselves can interfere with a believable 30's experience, and add details as you get to know the period better. This will also help find appropriate reference sites.

Comment: I need to know about the common jobs available, the average payment, common medicine, folk lore, racial prejudice effects on society, religion, political movements, etc.

Comment: There was a great answer by Samuel Russel here: http://history.stackexchange.com/a/2202/936

Comment: Cool bits here too: http://project1557.wetpaint.com/page/Catalog+Index

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic per [this meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/are-campaign-research-questions-on-topic-part-two) and belongs on history.se.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1930s section of the (rather old looking :)) [The People History](http://www.thepeoplehistory.com/1930s.html) site (found via google) appears to have somewhat brief yet interesting, relevant info on the era.

Note (and check) the links to the individual years in the middle of the right column too.

There are quite a number of other (imo poorly designed, yet quite) informative-looking, minor sites to be found as well - again via google. :) [An example](http://www.angelfire.com/retro/lisawebworld/30sproducts.html). [And another](http://nostalgiacafe.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=1930s), a closely related one.

And, of course, **Wikipedia also has [a general 1930s section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930s) and [a list of the individual years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_years)**.

Answer (score 10):

My go-to solution for this is to dig up scans or reproductions of old catalogs. I like the Sears catalogs quite a bit, as you get a nice cross-section of what people would have been buying at the time. There's several sites online, but here's one with the 1937 Christmas catalog. It's toy-focused, but there's some early electronics and kitchen appliances and such.

http://www.wishbookweb.com/1937_Sears_Wishbook/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Personally I go read books from the era; Rex Stout's mysteries are set in the 1930s and quite amusing to read. Also Raymond Chandler was writing at about that time. They tend to cover things from that era in the same manner as they would be using it (i.e. a violent one). Noir movies are also good for this.

Examples of things I've learned from these books:

-Elevators were around, but not the push button type. They had a lever and if you kept it down the elevator would crash into the floor. Thus why they had elevator operators. (Flure-de-Lace by Res Stout)

-Drugs often came as powders that you mixed into water. (The Woman in the Window (Fritz Lang, 1944))

-Pornography existed, but was illegal enough to go to jail for possessing it. (The Big Sleep by Raymond Chandler)